# Deploying SQL Changes Containing $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE())

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sqlcmd, sqlpackage

I have a [Database project](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833194%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio that I am attempting to deploy automatically to a test environment nightly. To accomplish this I am using TFS which leverages a PowerShell script to run "[SqlPackage.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx)" to deploy any changes that have occurred during the day.

Some of my procs contain logic that is run inside of a script that is part of a agent job step and contains the [following code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/use-tokens-in-job-steps)(In dynamic SQL):

```
$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))
```

When deploying changes that affect this proc, I get the following issue:

> SQL Execution error: A fatal error occurred. Incorrect syntax was
>   encountered while $(ESCAPE_SQUOTE( was being parsed.

This is a [known issue](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/635082/sqlcmd-bug-scripting-variable-not-defined), it appears as though that is not supported. It appears to be a function of the "SQLCmd" command misinterpreting the $( characters as a [variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh550080%28v=vs.103%29.aspx):

> "override the value of a SQL command (sqlcmd) variable used during a
>   publish action."

So how do I get around this? It seems to be a major limitation of "sqlcmd" that you can't disable variables, I don't see that parameter that supports that...

## Update 1

Seems as through you can disable variable substitution from "sqlcmd" by feeding it the "-x" argument([Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d43f6014-706c-4e48-a2ac-dc6d59400f8a/execute-script-containg-sql-agent-token-through-sqlcmd?forum=sqldatabaseengine), [Documentation](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/d43f6014-706c-4e48-a2ac-dc6d59400f8a/execute-script-containg-sql-agent-token-through-sqlcmd?forum=sqldatabaseengine)):

> -x (disable variable substitution)

Still don't see a way to do this from "SqlPackage.exe" though.

Comment: If you directly use the `sqlpackage.exe` command locally  will also get the same result. So this issue seems not related to TFS.

Comment: No it's an issue directly with the `sqlpackage.exe` command, what I really need is a way to disable parameters when deploying my code. I think sqlpackage calls sqlcmd when deploying but I don't see an option for either of them that allows you to disable variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to get around this is to refactor the "$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))" string into a scalar function, then setup a PowerShell script to directly invoke the "Sqlcmd" command with the "-x" parameter to "Create/Alter" said function before running "SqlPackage.exe".

Looks something like this in PowerShell:

```
$sql = @"
USE $database
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetJobID] ()
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN '$(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID))'
END

GO
"@;

Sqlcmd -S $servername -U $username -P $password -Q $sql -x;
```

This is a pretty poor workaround, but it does accomplish the task. Really hoping for something better.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that sqlcmd looks for the `$(` as a token, so separating those two characters is good enough. You can do this with a dynamic query that does nothing more than break the query into two strings:

```
DECLARE @query nvarchar(256) = N'... $' + N'(ESCAPE_SQUOTE(JOBID)) ...';
EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Comment: Works like a charm...!!! This is the only solution I've seen so far that solve both problems (passing variables to the sql script and using SQL Server Agent Tokens inside it). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I propose another workaround
my job has a step running : **DTEXEC.exe /SERVER "$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))"**

I just have to add a SQLCMD variable before:
**:setvar SRVR "$(ESCAPE_NONE(SRVR))"**

this way the toked is considered as SQLCMD variables $(SRVR) and is replaced by the requested value